# PrimeFaces autoComplete expand maxResults with moreText

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete

I have a autocomplete with a `maxResult` and a `moreText` property.

XHTML

```
<p:autoComplete maxResults="50" moreText="show more results" ...>
    <p:ajax event="moreText" listener="#{bean.onMoreText} />
</p:autoComplete
```

Bean

```
public void onMoreText(AjaxBehaviourEvent event) {
    AutoComplete ac = (AutoComplete)event.getSource();
    ac.setMaxResults(ac.getMaxResults() + 50);
}
```

What I want is that the result list expands for additional 50 rows. It does work this way but my the problem is that the result list hides after click on the `moreText` row. When I search again I'll get a result list with 100, 150, ... results.

How can I achive that the result list expands immediately after click on `show more results`

Comment: maybe in the oncomplete of the ajax call fake a click on the dropdown?

Comment: I have no dropdown button for this autocomplete

Comment: Then try faking a click on the input... Sorry...

Comment: created an answer from the previous edit.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution which fits my needs by adding this code

```
<p:autoComplete widgetVar="widgetVarName" completeMethod="#{bean.complete}">
    <p:ajax event="moreText" listener="#{bean.onMoreText}" />
</p:autoComplete>

public List<ResultType> complete(String qry) {
    setQryString(qry);
    // code to get results;
}

public void onMoreText(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete ac = (AutoComplete) event.getSource();
    ac.setMaxResults(ac.getMaxResults() + 30);
    executeJS("PF('widgetVarName').search('" + getQryString() + "')");
}

public void executeJS(String source) {
    org.primefaces.context.RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(source);
}
```

What is happening now is that after you click on the moreText row the suggestionList hides, maxResults gets increased and a new search starts with the qryString used for the completeMethod.

If someone has a better solution feel free to share it with us because my current solution is a terrible workaround which invokes a new database select for data that were already transferred.

Comment: Yeah, this is an ugly hack. The proper solution is https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8 . Feel free to create a PR or reach out to PrimeTek and inform about pro support / a quote to fix that issue. (I'm not employed by PrimeTek).