# Primefaces: extend autocomplete list

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Primefaces has [`autocomplete`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) component with a list of suggestions. One of the attributes calls `maxResults` where you can limit count of suggestions in list. If there is more variants that `maxResults` a button with three dots (which calls `moreText`) is shown at the end of list.
There is also `moreText` event, that fired when "When moreText is clicked".

The problem is that when I click this button, the list of suggestions just disappears without showing any result.
My expected behavior is that when I press `moreText` button, new suggestions are loaded. With or without using `moreText` event. Do I understand anything wrong?

---

I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244500/primefaces-autocomplete-expand-maxresults-with-moretext), but it looks more like dirty hack. I really don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following solution (workaround), by using a combination of AJAX Events and the Client Side API?

[PrimeFaces autoComplete expand maxResults with moreText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244500/primefaces-autocomplete-expand-maxresults-with-moretext)

Based on the Primefaces Doku `moreText` attribute is only for showing the text (last item in the list) and the `moreText` AJAX Event is there that you can come up with your own solution.

Comment: Yes, I wrote in my post that I don't want to use this kind of workaround. According to docs `moreText` event is fired "When moreText is clicked". Anyway, if "moreText" is just a text, why it's behaviour is like a button (highlighting, cursor pointer)?

Comment: Sorry I skipped the last line of your initial post. As far as I understand and used this feature you get the button with the AJAX event but nothing more.


Copied from the Primefaces User Guide:
**Limiting the Results**
Number of results shown can be limited, by default there is no limit. When the suggestions exceed the number of results, a text defined by moreText is displayed to indicate this case. There is no default action when the moreText is clicked, you need to use moreText ajax behavior event to handlemore results.